# Unable to find freeTDS version

Tags: sql-server, pyodbc, freetds

I am trying to find freeTDS version 0.82 specifically but havent been successful in that.I go to [this site](http://www.freetds.org/news.html)  and it gives me [this link](http://ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/stable/freetds-stable.tgz) .But when I download the file and unzip it - that shows version 0.91.I am specifically looking for version .82.Does anyone know where to find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your pick from [here](http://ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/old/0.82/).